# python library for drawing and documenting

Tags: python

I'm looking for something where I can make a report in python. the main thing is being able to draw, The drawings must be drawn to scale, so I can not use pixels.

right now I use pyuno, but documentation is not very good and when I search on the net most answers are at least 2 year old.

anyone have any ideas to another lib?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svg.charts comes to mind. Also, there are other SVG python libraries you can search in your favourite search engine.